# Trouble with changing the fractions into matrix-vector from

Tags: matrices, vectors, fractions, simplicial-stuff

I am curious about is there any way to turn the following expression into more elegant matrix-vector forms? This desired transform could contain a matrix-vector product.

$$f_1=\frac{DGX+KML}{DB-ML\frac{1+KB}{T-GX}},$$ and
$$f_2=\frac{DGX+KML}{DB\frac{T-GX}{1+KB}-ML},$$

where all the quantities are real numbers.

You could find that there are some obvious patterns in the two denominators and the numerators are the same. Now I want to re-rewrite the two fractions as a more concise form. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to also describe those variables: complex? real? natural numbers?

Comment: @NominalAnimal, thank you for reminding me. All the variables are the real numbers. Please see my update :)

Comment: I don't know about a matrix/vector expression, but if you use $$f = \frac{DGX + KML}{DBT - DBGX - KBML - ML}$$as a scale factor, then$$f_1 = (T - GX) f$$ and $$f_2 = (1 + KB) f$$Maybe that helps?

Comment: Properly grouped, $f$ is $$f = \frac{D \, GX + K \, ML}{DB ( T - GX ) - ML ( 1 + KB)}$$

Comment: @NominalAnimal, you are a Super Animal. Very helpful.